# why recursively map cannot compiler at c++20 in gcc and clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I write a recursively map as below, it compiles with c++17 in all msvc, gcc and clang. But it does not compile with c++20 in gcc and clang? any clue for that?

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct var : public std::variant<
    int,
    double,
    std::string,
    std::vector<var>,
    std::map<var, var>
> {};

int main() {
    var v1{ int{1} };
    var v2{ double{2.0} };
    var v3{ std::string{"3"} };
    var v4 = { std::vector{v1, v2, v3} };
    var v5 = { std::map<var, var>{ {v1, v2}, {v3, v4} } };
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a8Ga6nrs5

Comment: A recursive type can never work, as a type can't hold an instance of itself since it is not a complete type yet at the point of recursion. And `std::variant` can't hold an incomplete type. Also, `std::variant` is not meant to be derived from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not sure what you mean. The code can work and I have posted a godbolt link in question description.

Comment: "**[res.on.functions]/2** In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: ... (2.5) If an incomplete type (6.8) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component." "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior, "fails to compile" is another.