# How to define recursive std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I used to ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71963394/why-recursively-map-cannot-compiler-at-c20-in-gcc-and-clang) about recursive `std::variant`. According to comments, recursive `std::variant` is an undefined behavior, so I tried some tricks to make recursive `std::variant` legally.
The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/Yvv9Y415M) shows below:

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

template<typename T>
struct wrapper {
    wrapper(const T& t) {
        p = std::make_unique<T>(t);
    }

    wrapper(const wrapper& other) {
        p = std::make_unique<T>(*other.p.get());
    }

    wrapper& operator= (const wrapper& other) {
        p = std::make_unique<T>(*other.p.get());
        return *this;
    }
    ~wrapper() = default;

    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    auto operator<=> (const wrapper& other) const {
        return p <=> other.p;
    }
};

struct var : public std::variant<
    int,
    double,
    wrapper<std::vector<var> >,
    wrapper<std::map<var, var> >
> {};


int main() {
    var v1{ int{1} };
    var v2{ double{2.0} };
    
    wrapper vec(std::vector<var>{v1, v2} ) ;

    var v3(vec);

    std::map<var, var> m{};
    m[v1] = v2;
    wrapper ma{m};
    var v4(ma);
}
```

In my opinion, `std::unique_ptr` support incomplete type, so I use it as a wrapper. However, in gcc 11.3 and gcc 10.3, the code works well. But in gcc 11.1 and gcc 11.2, the code can't compile.
My questions are:

1. why gcc 11.1 and gcc 11.2 cannot compile the code?
2. Is such code legal in c++?
3. Any better way to write recursive `std::variant`?

Comment: don't inherit from `std::variant`. Define a type alias instead: `using var = std::variant`

Comment: But `using` cannot support recursive at all. @SergeyKolesnik

Comment: Also in the comment to your first question it was clearly stated that you can't have a type containing itself by value, because it hasn't been instantiated. No matter how many wrappers you are going to create, it is still a never-ending recursion.

Comment: It's not really recursive. `var` can instantiate with incomplete type `wrapper`, `wrapper` can instantiate with incomplete type `var`, so both of them can instantiate. It's a normal use of incomplete type. @SergeyKolesnik

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik the type doesn't contain itself by value. `std::unique_ptr` performs dynamic memory allocation, and is allowed to be instantiated with an incomplete template type.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I didn't see `std::unique_ptr`. My mistake

Comment: @macomphy yeah, I forgot about that

Comment: Just to clarify, the code compiles in all versions, but gcc 11.1 and 11.2 produce a link error.

Comment: For me, you are overcomplicating it. I would just forward declare a struct just like with a linked list `struct varin; using var = std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<varin>>; struct varin { var v; };`

Comment: `But in gcc 11.1 and gcc 11.2, the code can't compile` compiles fine here on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/4efP3YoMf . Please post the exact command line that you used, please post all verbatim error messages that you got. `Is such code legal in c++?` "looks fine"

Comment: @Patrick Roberts
 That's a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102654).

Comment: @KamilCuk Hi, I think your code compile is because of your code don't add `main` function block. And for your code of `varin`, I want to use `std::vector<var>` and 'std::map<var, var>`, does it support that?